# Restrict next_post_link() to current category

Tags: posts, next-post-link

The Codex disagrees with itself, so I'm stumped.

On `single.php` I am trying to use `next_post_link()` to display a link to the next post, with custom link text, within the same category as the current post.

The [Codex article on `next_post_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) says the parameters are $format, $link, $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, and $taxonomy. Its specific example for my scenario is

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE ); ?>
```

But when I use that exact code, no link is output at all. The rest of the Post fully renders, it's just missing the next post link HTML completely.

If I take out just the "TRUE" it outputs a link almost as desired:

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category' ); ?>
```

But it links to the next Post in any category, and I need to restrict it to the current category.

The [Codex article on Next and Previous Links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links) contradicts the article specifically on `next_post_link()`. It says the parameters are $format, $text, and $title. That would mean that you can't restrict the link to posts within the current category. Since the [Code Reference on `next_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/) matches the Codex on `next_post_link()` that seems likely to be the most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so there's a problem with Codes in this part, I guess.

> The Codex article on Next and Previous Links contradicts the article
>   specifically on next_post_link()

In that article you can clearly see, that it looked a little bit different. In the part describing `next_post_link` there is a note:

> Deprecated: previous_post() and next_post(). Use: -->
>   previous_post_link() and next_post_link() instead.

So most probably it is describing some old params...

## On the other hand, from PHP point of view...

The [official PHP manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> To specify a boolean literal, use the keywords TRUE or FALSE. Both are
>   case-insensitive.

So `true === TRUE` and `false === FALSE`.

On the [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) standard requires true, false and null to be in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems silly, but for some reason lowercasing the "true" solved the problem.

`<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', true ); ?>`

Comment: That is crazy. TRUE, True and true should all be the same.